# How can i use Zabbix Monitoring tool API to fetch all alerts for last 15 mins

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api

I am using zabbix for infrastructure monitoring. I want to export alerts real time to a centralized platform like splunk, ELK?
Can i pull all active alerts for last 15 mins using Zabbix API

ALso, is the api mature enough to implement auto close functionality?

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`problem.get` api](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/problem/get):

> This method is for retrieving unresolved problems. It is also
>   possible, if specified, to additionally retrieve recently resolved
>   problems.

A small python sample:

```
from zabbix.api import ZabbixAPI

zabbixServer    = 'http://yourserver/zabbix/'
zabbixUser      = 'someuser'
zabbixPass      = 'somepass'

zapi = ZabbixAPI(url=zabbixServer, user=zabbixUser, password=zabbixPass)

problems = zapi.problem.get()

for problem in problems:
    trigger = zapi.trigger.get (triggerids=problem['objectid'], selectHosts='extend')
    interface = zapi.hostinterface.get(hostids=trigger[0]['hosts'][0]['hostid'])
    group = zapi.hostgroup.get(hostids=trigger[0]['hosts'][0]['hostid'])

    enabled = "Enabled"
    if (trigger[0]['hosts'][0]['status'] == "1"):
        enabled = "Disabled"

    print "Group:{}; Host:{}; IP:{}; Problem:{}; {}".format(group[1]['name'],
                                                           trigger[0]['hosts'][0]['host'],
                                                           interface[0]['ip'],
                                                           trigger[0]['description'],
                                                           enabled )
```

Comment: Getting error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zabbix_alerting.py", line 7, in <module>
    zapi = ZabbixAPI(url=zabbixServer, user=zabbixUser, password=zabbixPass)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzabbix/api.py", line 180, in __init__
    self._login(user, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzabbix/api.py", line 210, in _login
    self.auth = self.user.login(user=user, password=password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzabbix/api.py", line 94, in fn
    args or kwargs urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>`

Comment: "Connection timed out". Did you set `zabbixServer` to the correct url?

Comment: yeah , i doubled check URL, username and password, but same error.
Do my user need some specific permissions? currently using admin

Comment: Are you running the script on your pc? On the server itself? On another linux machine? Did you check for firewall rules? Did you add a try..catch to the Zapii connect? You can also do a tcpdump to be sure... there are lots of thing to do and check.